# Customize application for Rimage disc systems

Tags: xml

Have anyone tried creating a customize application to integrate with the Rimage systems, especially the dsic publishing system? Like using its APIs, the Client API or the RapidAPI?
Can anyone share some concepts? Like in its XML part, and using its API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Rimage has many customers with customized applications using our API.  For further please call Rimage Inside Sales at 866-587-5903.